# find composer global install path as root

Tags: bash, php, path

I have some php packages installed globally using `php composer` within a script

```
sudo -u me composer global require "phpmd/phpmd"
```

I want to find the path of these globally installed php packages. When I run `which phpmd` as user `me` I get the full path.

> /home/me/.composer/vendor/bin/phpcs

However when I try and run the command as `sudo` I get nothing. I think this is because composer has been added globally and is in my user `me`s `PATH` while it is not present in sudo's `PATH`.

Instead I have tried

```
 path="$(sudo -u me which phpcs)"
```

But this also fails. However it succeeds for any program not installed through composer. How can I find the globally installed php packages through composer as `sudo`?

me's path

```
/home/me/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

sudo (su's) path

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: To troubleshoot, please show `me`'s and `root`'s path.  That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: updated the question @JuliePelletier

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as you can notice in the path difference, is that me's path includes `/home/me/.composer/vendor/bin`.  Sudo does not inherit the user's environment.

You would need to manually import it.  It's unclear why you'd want root to see a specific user's files in its path though.

To find a file, you can use the `find` command such as `find /home -name FileName`.

Comment: Manually import the composer path?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Julie's suggestion and some other answers on SO I came up with

```
 path="$(PATH=$PATH:/home/me/.composer/vendor/bin which phpcs)"
```

which works nicely